# Reading Text file line by line in QtCreator does not work

Tags: c++, qt, text-files

I am trying to code c++ in **QtCreator 3.4.2**. I create **Non Qt Project - Plain C++ Project**. I have a code, which tries to read content of text file line by line and output to the console screen. But it does not write anything. I run same code in **Visual Studio 2013** it works very well, without any problem. So What is the problem. The code is below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fin("input.txt");
    string s;
    while(getline(fin,s))
    {
        cout<<s<<endl;
    }
    fin.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Visual Studio and QtCreator may run the program in a different working directory. Check the settings [here](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-run-settings.html) to find out where QtCreator is launching your program, and then check if your file is there. Alternatively, use an absolute path to open the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the `input.txt` file is in the working directory of the program. Note that the working dir is *not* the same as the folder the program's .exe is in - you can set it from the project properties.